# VPN helps change the IP but why I still get banned from a website's chatroom?

Tags: vpn, ip

I was trying to enter a website's public chatroom powered by parachat. I don't want users and admins to look up my IP and location. So I bought a VPN and tried to hide my IP, but now I cannot log in to the chat, with error "access rejected from your IP address".  At one point with dynamic IP, i was able to access but after few minutes I was kicked out. I noticed I don't have access to some other websites due to the same reason. Is there a way to hide IP with VPN and be able to connect to such chat room? if no What are other ways to connect?

I don't have any intention to bother people in chat rooms or be involved in any kind of hacking activity. The purpose is educational and all I want is to protect my privacy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are essentially asking us to help you bypass an existing restriction (like blocking a VPN or [open proxies](http://service.parachat.com/knowledgebase/311/JN774-Access-rejected-from-your-IP-address.html))  solely for your own advantage. If you want to use a specific service you have to play by their rules. If you don't like these rules don't use the service.

Comment: It may be the VPN that's being banned

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think that's a very odd interpretation of the rules, otherwise virtually all questions about Tor for example would be banned, but they are not. It is completely on-topic and allowed to discuss censorship evasion techniques on Sec.SE. The only issue I see is that the question is more of a networking question than a security question.

Comment: @forest: The title of the question asks to explain why such restrictions might happen - which in my opinion is perfectly on-topic. Similar on-topic in my opinion are discussions how such restrictions are implemented and what techniques might allow bypasses based on how these restrictions work. But in the body of the question the OP specifically asks for ways to bypass the restrictions for one specific chat site. From this I interpret that the intend is not to understand the broader concepts but to bypass these specific restrictions - which I see as off-topic.

Comment: It reads to me like OP is asking how these bans works. He even gives a disclaimer that he is not out to bother them and just wants to learn how this is done and what attacks exist against said technique.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you run into is while your intentions may be noble many people use these VPN services to circumvent bans, geo restrictions etc.

So many site operators blacklist all IPs that are known to be associated with VPN providers, some go even further and add addresses associated with hosting providers to the blacklist to.